# Problems with js in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My JS work only if i reload page.

Description my problems

1.I have book

2.Book have description

3.In action show i have logic for present description

Logic:

```
   1. If description.length > 250 i show 250 symbols and show view_more button

   2. If user click on button then my js must work
```

4.When i on books#index => choose some book(#show)=> now i on book_page and i see view_button => when i click => nothing was happen
5. But if i reload page before click on button => my js work fine

My js

```
(function(window, document, undefined){
  window.onload = init;
  function init(){
    let btn_view_more = document.getElementById('button_for_view_more')
    let description_all = document.getElementById('book_description_all')
    let description_short = document.getElementById('book_description_short')

    btn_view_more.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    description_all.classList.remove('hide_description')
    description_short.style.display = 'none'
  });
 };
})(window, document, undefined);
```

But i have new version of my js

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
 myFunc();
})
function myFunc(){
 let btn_view_more = document.getElementById('button_for_view_more')
 let description_all = document.getElementById('book_description_all')
 let description_short = document.getElementById('book_description_short')

 btn_view_more.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
 description_all.classList.remove('hide_description')
 description_short.style.display = 'none'
 });
}
```

New version work fine even i don't reload page, but i have error in my console

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') (can't find id button_for_view_more)
```

What i want:
1. Js work even i don't reload page
2. Zero error in console

Comment: Your second JS code is best, but still need to add `;` after each line.

Comment: The error tells you what is wrong. JS can't find element with id "button_for_view_more", please post your HTML.

Comment: @Chiperific Yes, JS can't find but after this error, find and work. Its problem mb how rails render action show with dom or window stuff

Comment: DOM should be fully loaded when `"turbolinks:load"` happens, so the element should be on the page, unless `#btn_view_more` is added by JS or something.

Comment: You can add a breakpoint on `myFunct();` and check the HTML while paused to make sure.

Comment: I solved this, problems was in js, because this function work on all pages, but i need work only in page show

Comment: Great! Post your answer and you should be able to mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is connect js only to the page where it is used, delete from javascript/some.js and drop require from pack/application.js. You can also add a condition to your script that will check whether such an ID is currently on the page. And only after run the main block.